# Better setters for lists of objects

Tags: c#

Recently, when handling collections of objects of the same (base-)class,
I´ve recently found myself writing something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    public bool PropertyA {get; set;}
}

class EncapsulatingClass {
    private List<SomeClass> list = new();
    private bool propA;
    public bool PropertyA { 
        get { return propA; }
        set { 
            propA = value;
            foreach(SomeClass instance in list)
                instance.PropertyA = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is of course so I don´t have to use `foreach` every time I want to set a property for the collection. While this works fine, I feel like this requires a lot of code for something simple and a lot of repitition with each property.

Is there a better solution, like extracting the logic of "apply this for the property of the same name for each object in the list" into a function and just calling that in the setters?

Comment: An extension method that works on enumerable.

Comment: you can simply create a generic base class holding your data.

Answer (score 2):

There is the issue of ownership of the property. If you need to enforce synchronization such that setting `PropertyA` ins the encapsulating class, all the instances in the list also use the *same value*.

For example

```
class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(EncapsulatingClass parent)
    {
        Parent=parent;
    }

    public EncapsulatingClass Parent { get; }
    public bool PropertyA { get => Parent.PropertyA; }
}
class EncapsulatingClass
{
    private List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>();
    private bool propA;
    public bool PropertyA
    {
        get { return propA; }
        set
        {
            propA = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you have multiple `PropertyA` values, one for each instance, and then you have to decide which one is the *master* value, and what to do if some are different.

Comment: I thought about that for classes I define, but what If `SomeClass` is a class that I did not define and can´t change the behavior of?

Comment: @noel - I feel this might be a bad design to keep manually updating lists of records based on something defined outside of the class. Encapsulation means everything important for `SomeClass` is included within. The issue here is having a property within the `EncapsulatingClass` that reflects on the state of all the records in the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering what it is you are doing to need this so often. It makes me think there's a flaw in the design of your application you could avoid by restructuring something but it's difficult to say without more information.

For your specific problem I would discard `EncapsulatingClass` and use the `ForEach` method on `List<T>` for a little more concise code:

```
myList.ForEach(s => s.PropertyA = true);
```

Alternatively, if you don't always use `List<T>` you can write your own extension method to work on all `IEnumerable`s:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var t in source)
        action(t);
}

// Call it just like previously:
myIEnumerable.ForEach(s => s.PropertyA = true);
```

Of course, this is still cumbersome if you need to do it a lot. But I suspect if you do, it's probably a flaw in the design.

Comment: Until you end up double enumerating a database query because you want to do something to every item in the result and can't track down your bug. I'd steer clear of this particular extension method. There's an answer from Eric Lippert *somewhere* on SO that goes into why this method exists for list and not for a generic enumerable. I'll see if I can find it

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 to a degree I agree with you, but I think that's more a question of using `IEnumerable`s the right way. You could almost say the same about `Any`, `Contains`, `Count` etc. all of which are standard `IEnumerable` methods.

Answer (score 1):

I might approach this with a custom List class providing a single mass update method.

```
public class EasyUpdateList<T> : List<T>
{
    public void UpdateAll(Action<T> update)
    {
        if (update == null)
            return;

        foreach (T item in this)
            update(item);
    }
}
```

Now you don't need a specific encapsulating class, you can just create a new EasyUpdateList and update any number of properties across the collection using the UpdateAll method.

```
EasyUpdateList<MyClass> list = new EasyUpdateList<MyClass>();

list.Add(instance1);
list.Add(instance2);
...

list.UpdateAll(x =>
{
    x.Property1 = "Value1";
    x.Property2 = "Value2";
});
```

This still uses a foreach loop but is much more generic and you don't have to change your other classes or write repeated code for each one.

Of course you could also achieve this with an extension method for a List class if you don't want a new class.

```
public static void UpdateAll<T>(this IList<T> list, Action<T> update)
{
    if (update == null)
        return;

    foreach (T item in list)
        update(item);
}
```

Comment: The latter. *Prefer delegation over inheritance*